# Is it possible to collect payments from VISA, Discover, and PayPal into a Mastercard?

Tags: paypal, shopify, e-commerce, credit-card, mastercard

I am a college student and I want to launch an online store for dropshipping. I am allowed to have one credit card, where I live, say Mastercard. But for the customers convenience I would like to enable VISA, Discover, Mastercard, American express, Debit card, and PayPal checkout.  I know that there is a PayPal credit card that allows payments from all these cards but it requires a business license, which I am not allowed to have as a student. Is there a way I can receive payments from the above mentioned cards to a Mastercard? If there is a better solution to my problem I would like to hear it from you. Thanks!

Comment: Payments from online stores don't get applied to a credit card, they get deposited into a bank account.  Look for a Merchant Account.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up an online store, you will also be signing up with a *Payment gateway* that will be collecting money on your behalf and transferring it to you. In this way, you will be able to set up your store to be able to accept any payment methods supported by the payment gateway(s) that you set up, and any money you make will be transferred from the gateway to the account that you registered with. This might be a credit card or directly to a bank account depending on what the gateway supports.

Using a trusted payment gateway (such as Stripe, Braintree, PayPal, Authorize.net, etc.) will let you focus on your store and not have to worry about accepting credit card information directly, and you will get your earnings transferred to you regularly in a form that you can accept.  Note also that taking credit card info directly comes with a host of security concerns and regulations.  By using a payment gateway you will never see anyone's credit card info directly, so you won't have to worry about all the security and legal concerns surrounding that.  The gateway companies make their money by taking a small transaction fee for each purchase, but this fee is definitely worth it to get your business started.